# Looping through rows in Dataset and replace value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dataset

I have a dataset that is being populated by a database query (which is all working fine). In the database, there is a column that contains "models". Some of these models have a "+" character in them, which causes problems later on when the model is used in a URL query string (since the + is interpreted as a space). So I'm trying to replace each value in that column with the encoded URL string.

I've tried a few different sets of code. Right now I have:

```
For Each row As DataRow In models.Tables(0).Rows
    row.Item("Model") = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(row.Item("Model"))
Next
Me.ModelsList.DataSource = models
Me.ModelsList.DataBind()
```

I've tried variations on this, but nothing works. It's not replacing the value with the modified value (that is, the URL on the rendered page isn't changed). I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I can't think of what it might be.

Comment: Have you tried models.SaveChanges after you've finished looping? Just an idea.

Comment: @DNNDev.co.za: There is no DataTable.SaveChanges. I assume you mean [`AcceptChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.80).aspx) which does something completely different(changes every DataRow's `RowState` to unchanged).

Comment: Isn't DataMember a DataGrid property? It's not a property of DataSet.

Comment: FYI @TimSchmelter, the OP is using a DataSet (not a DataTable).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a Pre_Render event that was overriding the code above (which was in the Page_Load event). Just had to change that and it works.